# Filtro com Linq ou Lambda utilizando Join e Group By

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Boa Tarde

Em uma tabela onde sempre é inserido novos registros podem ocorrer de ter a mesma Date e o mesmo RateCode, porém eu quero pegar uma lista dessa tabela mas  para cada grupo Date, RateCode gostaria que me retornasse o último registro inserido, garantindo que vai ser sempre a última linha inserida, como estou utilizando Entity Framework não posso rodar a query para me retornar o resultado, acredito ser melhor usar lambda ou LINQ para filtrar os dados, porém, não tenho muita experiência em usos complexos e até o momento não estou conseguindo implementar a lógica, em SQL filtraria dessa forma do jeito mais simples.

```
select a.* 
  from DailyRates a
  join (select Max(Id) as Id, Date, RateCode
          from DailyRates
         where RoomTypeId = 79
         group by Date, RateCode) b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Não entendi bem o que tu quer pegar. Seria o último registro inserido, isso?

Comment: Sim, umas lista, para cada par Date, Rate code o último registro inserido, por exemplo, eu tenho 2 linhas, Id = 1, Date = '11/05/2017', RateCode= 1, Id = 2, Date = '11/05/2017', RateCode= 1 na lista vão ter datas duplicadas pois somente é inserido novos registros e nunca deletado, porém eu preciso garantir que vou sempre pegar o último registro por isso tenho que agrupar e capturar a linha com o maior registro, porém pode vir N linhas com N duplicadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom consegui resolver com LINQ, primeira lista capturo do banco com os filtros e linhas duplicadas, na segunda filtro somente as linhas mais recentes com os registros mais atuais inseridos.

```
List<DailyRate> dailyRates = oDailyDao.All().Where(x => x.RoomTypeId == dailyRate.RoomTypeId && x.RoomType.Company.SeriesNumber == sSeriesNumber).ToList();

List<DailyRate> dailyRatesFiltro = (from a in dailyRates
                                    join b in (from x in dailyRates
                                              group x by new { x.Date, x.RateCode } into z
                                              select new { Id = z.Max(a => a.Id) }) on  a.Id equals b.Id
                                    select a).ToList();
```